# Getting the most recent releases of gcc / g++ (11.0 or 10.2) on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: apt, compiling, c++, g++

I'd like to get the latest releases of g++ (and clang) via package manager (apt).
Currently I need to compile gcc/g++ on my own which needs really a lot of time.

Are there any repositories with "special packages" like g++-10-2, g++-11 or just g++-master?

I'd be really nice :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't the Ubuntu repositories have the latest versions of software?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151283/why-dont-the-ubuntu-repositories-have-the-latest-versions-of-software)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In general it is a good way to go. But because I'm developer who uses C++20 features I'd like to get latest releases (for my dev). For me it would be okay to add "beta" or "dev" repositories (called PPA). I know such software can contain new not fixed bugs...

Comment: I did already: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test

Comment: I would like to get a "developers' PPA" or "Ubuntu+1 repositories"

Comment: Actually these Linux systems are in virtual environment and used only to compile C++ - so I don't care about system stability or whatever...

Comment: The "dev" release of Ubuntu is currently 20.10, not 20.04. It will be released in October 2020. 20.04 has no "dev" repositories since it's already released.

Comment: Is it possible to update ubuntu to version 20.10 (I use WSL - which has only 20.04)?
In the answeres linked by N0rbert I found some nice tool "Homebrew", I'll check it...

Comment: It seems to have only old versions too...

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no way to get up-to-date packages for ubuntu, you have to built them by yourself...

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution via ppa.

You can find the instructions here: [Install g++ 11 on Ubuntu 20.04](https://lindevs.com/install-g-on-ubuntu/)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1212071)